# How should I prepare meat to be ground?

Tags: meat, raw-meat

I am having trouble at the moment with my new mincer because bits of connective tissue keep getting caught in the works and clogging it up, stopping the mince coming out. However I'm not quite sure how to prevent it. I try to take obvious bits off, but a lot of it is in very thin sheets which are challenging to remove, especially when the meat is cubed.

Comment: Are you chilling your meat before feeding it into the grinder?

Answer (score 2):

My husband and I regularly grind our own meat. What we do is trim the meat *before* cubing. If any connective tissue / silver-skin is on the outside of the meat or running through the meat we are getting it off of a larger piece of meat, which is much easier because you can get a better hold on it.

We also use a filet knife for trimming the tough tissue. It allows you to trim much closer and with much more control, minimizing any waste.

And last but not least, chilling the meat helps also. While you don't want it frozen, firm is easier to handle.

Comment: What cuts do you tend to use? Generally chuck from the butchers comes pre cubed in the UK

Comment: @Tom just ask them not to cube it :) They should have some 'out the back', and if not, they will order it in and keep it for you.

Comment: BTW, a good meat grinder with sharp, well aligned knife will deal with the connective tissue without a hitch, the meat will be minimally less tender at the benefit of avoiding the most bothersome part of the work (maybe second most, after washing the grinder).